# How am I meant to split code between src/Lib.hs and app/Main.hs in a new stack project?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I was following the [stack guide](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md) and I got a new project setup (yay!).

It generated the following file layout:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── Main.hs
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
├── helloworld.cabal
├── Setup.hs
├── src
│   └── Lib.hs
├── stack.yaml
└── test
    └── Spec.hs
```

According to the "[Files in helloworld](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#files-in-helloworld)" section of the guide:

> The app/Main.hs, src/Lib.hs, and test/Spec.hs files are all Haskell source files that compose the actual functionality of our project (we won't dwell on them here).

I really wish they had dwelled on that for a second, because I have no idea what the distinction between `app/Main.hs` and `src/Lib.hs` should be. Which code should I put where?

**In what ways am I supposed to divide code between `app/`, `src/`, `app/Main.hs` and `src/Lib.hs`?**

If I'm just writing an application or just writing a library, do I need both files/directories?

Comment: If you do not have an executable you can delete main.hs and the respective parts in the cabal file. In the other case i would try to provide as much functionality as a library and only have a minimal io related executable. But if you are new to haskell do as you feel comfortable and don't worry too much. Ultimately i think, this is more a matter of style/taste than a formally answerable question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This separation of modules into folders can be any way you want. The naive idea is that you put almost all logic into the `Lib` folder. `Main.hs` then just

- imports required parts from `Lib`,
- reads command-line arguments, and
- runs stuff.

You can rename `app` into `executables` and change the corresponding lines in `.cabal` file. Actually, you can come up with an arbitrary file hierarchy.

In our company project, we use another but also very popular approach. And our file hierarchy looks like this:

```
.
|-- bench
|-- src
    |-- exec1
        |-- Main.hs
    |-- exec2
        |-- Main.hs
    |-- SuperCoolLibrary
        |-- LibModule1.hs
        |-- LibModule2.hs
|-- test
|-- Setup.hs
```

Other `stack.yaml`, `.cabal`, etc. files are not shown here.

Actually, if you are writing an application, you can just create one `Main.hs` file and put all logic inside the `main` function. You won't believe it but as a Haskell lecturer I saw such code from my students :(
Though I don't suggest you write code that way.

If you are writing a library then you don't need `Main.hs` files and the `main` function at all. You can look at a simple example like this library (it allows you to automatically generate command-line options from data types): [optparse-generic](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Optparse-Generic-Library)

I hope I helped clearing up your confusion.

Comment: Thanks! Some relevant cabal documentation regarding what you said about changing corresponding lines in `.cabal` - https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#editing-the-.cabal-file

Answer (score 5):

The main reason it's typically set up like this even for an application is for writing tests. Say you create a default stack project called `foo`, the test suite `foo-test` will depend on the `foo` library, as will the `foo-exe`. If you were to put all your functions into `app/Main.hs`, then those functions cannot be tested from the `foo-test` test suite.

If you're just playing around and don't care about having a test suite, you could base your stack project on the `simple` template:

```
$ stack new foo simple
```

If you'd like to set up testing, I like `tasty`. You'd modify your `.cabal` file something like this:

```
test-suite foo-test
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      test
  main-is:             Spec.hs
  build-depends:       base
                     , foo
                     , tasty
                     , tasty-hunit
                     , tasty-quickcheck
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Then take a look [at the example](https://github.com/feuerbach/tasty#example).